# Isn't lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted CoroutineScope available in a functions lambda?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, kotlin-coroutines

I have following code snippet:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    setDiscrepancyChips(basicRegisterItemList = Repository.getTableSet(RegisterType.DISCREPANCY),
                        chipGroup = fragmentOfflinePhotoCategorySelection.selectionChipsPhotoCategoryDiscrepancyChipGroup,
                        registrationSetResult = Repository.getRegistrationDiscrepancyIdSet(assignmentId = assignmentId)
                    ){discrepancyId, isChecked ->
                        Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: P103: discrepancyId=$discrepancyId, isChecked = $isChecked")

                        Repository.updateRegistrationDiscrepancyId(assignmentId = assignmentId, discrepancyId = discrepancyId, isChecked)
                    }
}
```

Here my compiler complaints that `Repository.updateRegistrationDiscrepancyId` isn't inside the coroutine body...

[image]

...will this say that a lambda needs to define it's own CoroutineScope like this ?

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
     setDiscrepancyChips(basicRegisterItemList = Repository.getTableSet(RegisterType.DISCREPANCY),
                        chipGroup = fragmentOfflinePhotoCategorySelection.selectionChipsPhotoCategoryDiscrepancyChipGroup,
                        registrationSetResult = Repository.getRegistrationDiscrepancyIdSet(assignmentId = assignmentId)
                    ){discrepancyId, isChecked ->
                        Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: P103: discrepancyId=$discrepancyId, isChecked = $isChecked")
                        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                            Repository.updateRegistrationDiscrepancyId(assignmentId = assignmentId, discrepancyId = discrepancyId, isChecked)
                        }
                    }
}
```

I feel a bit awkward to create two CoroutineScopes within each other, or should I see the   lambda as a separate code block which needs to creates its own coroutine scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda essentially is nothing but a function and like any other function in kotlin, a lambda can be marked with `suspend` modifier.

when lambda is invoked, it starts executing like a normal kotlin function, if its a suspending lambda then it can call other suspending functions but if its not then it cant do that, which is the problem you face.

think of it this way, lets say you have folowing code

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
    someFun()
}

private fun someFun(){
    Repository.updateRegistrationDiscrepancyId()
    // you get the same error as you do now
}
```

Your lambda is like `someFun`, since its not suspending, it cant call suspending functions.

Another option then the one you already used is to mark the lambda parameter in `setDiscrepancyChips` with `suspend` modifier. and if `setDiscrepancyChips` itself is suspending then the lambda will start executing on `setDiscrepancyChips`'s coroutine scope(still depends on how it invokes lambda), otherwise it must start a new coroutine to invoke the lambda